# SQL Server: explanation needed to understand combination of DATEADD and DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, stored-procedures

I am pretty new to SQL and use the following lines within a Select in order to get the first and last Monday of October (`@selYear` defines the year).

Can someone here tell me how to adjust this so that it returns the second, third and fourth Monday of October + **provide me an explanation so that I can modify this further for other dates** ?

Do I just have to change the last 0 in the first formula to 7, 14 or 21 in order to add the additional weeks ?
And if instead of Monday I want Friday or Thursday would I then just replace the 6 by 4 or 3 ?

```
--1st Monday in October
DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, DATEADD(m, 10-1, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, @selYear), 6)))/7*7, 0),
--last Monday in October
DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, DATEADD(m, 10, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, @selYear), 6)))/7*7, -7),
```

**Edit:** @selYear in my case is defined as `@selYear nvarchar(4)` and the table column I am inserting this into is formatted as datetime - maybe this is wrong as the result should always be a valid date ?

Many thanks in advance, Mike.

Comment: @dean - `@selyear` appears in positions where it looks like a date is expected. If you cast `2014` to a date, you get `1905-07-08`. So I'd suggest repeating your test but with `@selYear` as a datetime from some point in this year.

Comment: Thanks, All. The above works correctly for me - this is only about how to adjust this for the other dates. Of course, if I am not doing this the proper way or it works just as a coincidence please let me know as well. The result should always be a valid date. :)

Comment: Well, the first thing to mention is that I think that the shown query is broken - from 2100 onwards. From what I can work out, it's effectively computing this years offset from a year in the 1900-06 range that has the same calendar as this year, and then applies that offset back to that year to get the correct dates. But that fails to work once we get past 2100 because that year won't be a leap year.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Thanks - this is something that is not relevant for what I need.

Comment: Which is exactly what they were saying about the year 2000 back in the 60s and 70s (and for some, the 80s and 90s) and produced the Y2K problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @date as date = '20141001' -- this is for october 2014
declare @n as int = 0
while (@n<7)
begin
if ((select DATENAME(dw,@date)) = 'Monday') -- write which day you want as pivot 
    break
else
begin
set @n = @n+1
set @date = DATEADD(D,1,@date)
end
end

select @date  first
, DATEADD(D,7,@date)  second    
, DATEADD(D,14,@date) third
, DATEADD(D,21,@date) fourth
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I would need to stick with something close to what I have above as I will have to use this with different years and months.

Comment: you can use with whatever year or month ,, say you want sundays of januray 2013

just change @date value to '20130101' and pivot day to 'Sunday'

Comment: Thanks but sorry, this is not flexible enough for me as I have a longer list of dates to be calculated here. I would just need an explanation on how to modify the above lines.